# Expected number of successive events in a die experiment

Tags: probability, expected-value

Suppose that we have an unfair die. We roll the die $n$ times. What is the expected number of times one face (say 3) succeeds another face (say 5)? In other words what is the expected number of occurrences of the pair 53 in the sequence.

Comment: So any side can have a probability from 0-1 and the number of sides is 6? And how comes you can have a pair (5,3)? Are you rolling 2 dices or what do you mean with "pair"?

Comment: @KaPy3141 Suppose that we roll it 10 times and we get the sequence: 2412653453. In this sequence the pair 53 appears 2 times. And yes, any side can have a probability from 0-1 and the number of sides is 6.

Comment: Use linearity of expectation to compute the mean number of 5-->3 transitions.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y$ be the expected number of $3$'s in the last $n-1$ trials. And, let $X$ be the number of occurrences of $53$. Let $p,q$ be the probability of having 3 and 5, respectively. Then, 
$$E[X]=E[E[X|Y]]=E[Yp] = pE[Y]=(n-1)pq$$

Here is an example:

```
from scipy.stats import rv_discrete
import numpy as np

p, q = 1/5, 1/9
pmf = np.random.random((6,))
pmf[[2,4]] = p, q
others = np.random.random((4,))
others = others / others.sum() * (1-p-q)
pmf[[0,1,3,5]] = others

obj = rv_discrete(values = tuple([range(1,7), pmf]))

N = int(1e6)
n = 30
c = 0

all_dice = obj.rvs(size = (N,n))

for i in range(N):
    dice = all_dice[i,:]
    inds = np.where(dice == 3)[0]-1
    inds = inds[inds >= 0]
    c += sum(dice[inds] == 5)

c / N, (n-1) * p * q
```

Has the following output:

```
(0.6447, 0.6444444444444445)
```

Comment: I don't feel this is right. $E[X|Y]$ not alway is $Y/6$.

Comment: This is the correct approach, but because the question is about an *unfair* die, it would be appropriate to provide a relevant example and a general formula.

Comment: Completely forgot the [un]fairness, thank you @whuber.